# Select value from group with the highest count

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Say I have two sets; Candy and Region. For each Candy I have one-to-many names of what that candy is called in a certain Region (CandyRegion).

I want to build a list of Candy objects where only a single CandyRegion.Name is selected. The CandyRegion.Name selected is determined by the most popular Region (where the number of candies available in that Region is the greatest).

Whats a suitable way to perform the query to find the most popular Region? What I have so far:

```
context.Candys
    .Select(c => c.CandyRegions
        .OrderByDescending(cr => 
            /* 
             * Order CandyRegion by Candy.CandyRegion.Count outside
             * the context of c? 
             */
            context.CandyRegions.Count(cr2 => cr2.RegionId == cr.RegionId)
        )
        .FirstOrDefault()
    )
    .ToList();
```

I have a feeling that the performance of the above query is going to be a problem.

Edit: Classes

```
public class Candy
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual List<CandyRegion> CandyRegions { get; set; } 
}

public class Region
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual List<CandyRegion> CandyRegions { get; set; } 
}

public class CandyRegion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...

    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }

    public int CandyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Candy Candy { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You mention that you have two sets. By your code snippet, the candy object contains a collection of candy regions, correct?  If this is the case, you technically have an object which contains a collection as opposed to two separate collections which implies that you'd need a join clause of some sort.

Comment: @JamesShaw Yes, CandyRegion is a collection on Candy and Region. Region would be the second set. Candy and Region are joined by CandyRegion.

Comment: @DamonPollard I think you should also post Candy and Region classes in question! It creates confusion..

Comment: That additional snippet definitely makes it easier to determine what you are trying to accomplish and how.

Comment: It seems that Candy to Region can be in many to many relation. Why did you added this third CandyRegion? Is it there to attach candy with many region and region with many candy?

Comment: Your CandyRegion object contains a reference to a single Candy and a single Region. That suggests that CandyRegion is a bridge class. A 1to1 relationship to either Candy or Region.  I don't see the one to many relationship that you mentioned in your description.

Comment: I meant that for every Candy, I will have at least one CandyRegion. There will never be a case where I have a Candy with 0 CandyRegions. However, Regions can have 0 CandyRegions.

Comment: Heh, having a collection of CandyRegions contained within either your Candy or Region class while a CandyRegion contains a single instance of Candy or Region typically causes circular dependencies but that's another issue and off topic. :)

Comment: What your object models suggest there is that a candy has many candyregions and a region has many candyregions.  Perhaps I'm wrong.  Give me a few minutes, I am going to throw together an example.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick, although I haven't tested it.  Let me know this solves your problem.

```
Context.Candys
                .Where(c => c.Id == c.CandyRegions
                    .FirstOrDefault(cr => cr.RegionId == c.CandyRegions
                        .GroupBy(grp => grp.RegionId)
                            .Select(r => new
                                            {
                                                RegionId = r.Key,
                                                Total = r.Count()
                                            }
                                    ).OrderByDescending(r => r.Total)
                                                .Take(1)
                                                .First().RegionId
                                    ).CandyId
                        )
                        .ToList();
```

*Explanation of what's going on above...*

Since the Region and the Candy both use CandyRegion as a bridging table, you can group the Candy's foreign key collection of CandyRegion by it's RegionId.

This provides an easy way of determining what the count is for each grouped set. Now that you have the counts, we want to order them from highest to lowest, and grab just the topmost item. We don't care about the rest.

Once that's done, it would just be a matter of selecting the first CandyRegion contained in the list that matches the determined RegionId and then comparing it's CandyId to the CandyID of the same CandyRegion.

Finally, when that's all done, you return the result as a list which would be the said Candies that you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Any specific reason to query against `context` for getting count while you can have c.CandyRegion with you?

Below query will result in join and query with `context` will result in inner query.

```
context.Candy
    .Select(c => c.CandyRegion
        .OrderByDescending(cr => 
            /* 
             * Order CandyRegion by Candy.CandyRegion.Count outside
             * the context of c? 
             */
            c.CandyRegion.Count()
        )
        .FirstOrDefault()
    )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This would get me the most popular candy (candy in most regions) and not the region with the most candies. I want to find the later.

Comment: @DamonPollard Which part of query makes you think that this will give you candy instance instead of candyregion instance?

Comment: Sorry, I meant with regards to the change you made, not the result of the query. c.CandyRegion.Count() will give me the candy with the most regions, resulting in the wrong order.

Comment: @DamonPollard Is the `regionId` foreign key that relates Candy with region in Candy table?